# Matrix dimension must agree but they are correct

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix which is assigned variable a.

the matrix has a size of <112 * 92 uint8>

Hence i ran the following code

```
b = a'; c = b .*a;
```

However, it is said that the dimension does not match which i am unable to resolve the reason why

Comment: It wont work because size of `a` is 112x92 and size of `b` is 92x112. Maybe instead of `.*` operator you mean `*`?

Comment: @Marcin i have used * but it doesn't work also. It gave an error of mtimes is not fully supported for integer classes

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: Version Matlab r2013A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you show is performing elementwise multiplication, where the two matrices must be of identical shape.

From the answer you gave to @Marcin's question I assume you originally tried to do a matrix multiplication `a*b` where the matrix dimensions are compatible, and received the eroor message you mention. The problem causing this message is nothing to do with matrix dimensions: Matlab does not support the matrix multiplication operator for matrices of type `uint8`, only the overload which multiplies a matrix of this type by a scalar. In fact this is true for any integer type.

If you want to multiply matrices of integer type, you must cast each to a floating point type, multiply and cast back, e.g.:

```
 c = uint8(single(a)*single(b'));
```